# How can I create a bash function to document bash aliases

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to write a bash function that only uses grep,awk,sed to print out documentation for bash aliases.

I want to use ### as a documentation header for a section of related aliases.
I want to use ## as a documentation string for a description of an alias

An example ~/.bash_aliases file would look like this

```
### Docker

## List running containers
alias drc="docker ps -a | grep 'Up'"

## List IDs of running containers
alias didr="docker ps -aq | grep 'Up'"

## List IDs of stopped containers
alias dids="docker ps -aq | grep 'Exited' | awk '{print $1}'"


### Ansible

## Run ansible-playbook
alias ap='ansible-playbook'

## Run ansible-playbook on local host
alias apl='ansible-playbook -c local'
```

Given the .bash_aliases file above I would like to create a bash function named "aliases" that prints the following output

```
Docker
-------------------------------------------------
drc   - List running containers
didr  - List IDs of running containers
dids  - List IDs of stopped containers


Ansible
-------------------------------------------------
ap    - Run ansible-playbook
apl   - Run ansible-playbook on local host
```

I would like to put the "aliases" function in the top of my .bash_aliases file so that when I source the .bash_aliases file I can just run "aliases" to see my documentation.

I saw something at the bottom of this thread
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128736/how-to-document-my-custom-bash-functions-and-aliases
that appeared to come close to a solution.  I've been tweaking it for quite a while and doing lots of google searches but I'm still struggling to get the results I want.

I would appreciate any help.  Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to the answer from Ed Morton and the answers to these other questions

- [Can you use heredocuments to embed AWK in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489995/can-you-use-heredocuments-to-embed-awk-in-a-bash-script)
- [How to assign a heredoc value to a variable in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167746/how-to-assign-a-heredoc-value-to-a-variable-in-bash)

I was able to come up with a solution.

Here is an example ~/.bash_aliases file now

```
IFS='' read -r -d '' VAR <<'EOF'
sub(/^###[[:space:]]+/,"") {
    printf "\n%s%s\n----------------------------------------------------------\n", rs, $0
    rs = "\n\n"
}

sub(/^##[[:space:]]+/,"")  {
    desc = $0
}

$1 == "alias" && sub(/=.*/,"",$2) {
    printf "%-10s - %s\n", $2, desc
}
EOF

function aliases() {
    echo
    grep -A10000 "^###" ~/code/bash_aliases/.bash_aliases | awk -f <(echo "$VAR") 
    echo
}


### Docker

## List running containers
alias drc='docker ps -a | grep 'Up''

## List IDs of running containers
alias didrc='docker ps -aq | grep "Up"'

## List IDs of stopped containers
alias dids='docker ps -aq | grep "Exited" | awk "{print $1}"'


### Ansible

## Run ansible-playbook
alias ap='ansible-playbook'

## Run ansible-playbook on local host
alias apl='ansible-playbook -c local'
```

After you run

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

you can run

```
aliases
```

The documented aliases will be displayed.

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Nice plan. What EXACTLY is the problem?

Comment: This was the first time I've ever posted on StackOverflow. Sorry for not being clear.  Next time I will ask a more specific question.

Comment: I don't know why this is still down-voted after the updates. This is very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for any other text manipulation you should use awk and once you are using awk you don't need to additionally do anything with grep or sed

```
$ cat tst.awk
sub(/^###[[:space:]]+/,"") {
    printf "%s%s\n---------------\n", rs, $0
    rs = "\n\n"
}

sub(/^##[[:space:]]+/,"")  {
    desc = $0
}

$1 == "alias" && sub(/=.*/,"",$2) {
    printf "%s\t- %s\n", $2, desc
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Docker
---------------
drc     - List running containers
didr    - List IDs of running containers
dids    - List IDs of stopped containers


Ansible
---------------
ap      - Run ansible-playbook
apl     - Run ansible-playbook on local host
```

All of the sed language constructs to do anything across multiple lines became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted in terms of printing output! I originally wanted to have a function in my ~/.bash_aliases that would print this out but the more I thought about it, having the awk code in a different file gives me the ability to use the same documentation comments (###, ##) in other files.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

With sed. As first step for you:

```
sed -nE 's/^### (.*)/\n\1\n-------/p;TA;b;:A;s/^## (.*)/\1/;tX;b;:X;h;n;s/^alias (.*)=.*/\1\t\t- /;G;s/\n//p' ~/.bash_aliases
```

Output:

```
Docker
-------
drc             - List running containers
didr            - List IDs of running containers
dids            - List IDs of stopped containers

Ansible
-------
ap      - Run ansible-playbook
apl             - Run ansible-playbook on local host
```